# How to debug why another vendor's MSI installer runs spontaneously?

Tags: windows-installer, installer

Problem: When some people run my app *the MSI-based installer for some other program will spontaneously start to run* and try to reinstall itself.

**How can I determine precisely what the reason for the reinstall is**?

Maybe there is some shared dependency (a registered COM DLL perhaps) that our app and the other software both refer to..?

I have gotten sample MSI log files from customers ([using instructions here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging)) but there are > 20K lines of information which I can't easily interpret.

---

The root cause problem might originate with my app, or might be with the other vendor, but regardless users shouldn't be faced with this and I'd like to be able to understand & ideally fix this problem.

---

Notes:

- My app is a "legacy" VB6 program.
- Typically the other installer which runs is an AutoDesk product
- Log file is named `MSI340f4.LOG` having 32416 lines

  - It mentions `C:\Windows\Installer\4c26ff.msi` and `roamer.msi` (without path)

Comment: Are you trying to identify which MSI is being ran or how to prevent the MSI from being ran.  The solution would be vastly different.

Comment: @Ramhound the goal would be to prevent the problem from occurring. Since the MSI isn't owned by me, I don't really care per se what it is, though I could imagine this might be an important incidental detail, perhaps.

Comment: Update your question to indicate which MSI is bring ran.  Is something actually being installed or it is just being launched?

Comment: @Ramhound The log files I have list several .MSI filenames. I'm not sure what they are or how they relate. They are from another vendor. It appears that the MSI being run is trying to reinstall / repair itself.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer

Comment: @Ramhound any guidance regarding what specifics would be useful I would appreciate. This is another vendor's product causing the problem so I have very limited knowledge about what it is doing... thanks

Comment: I have asked for which MSI is being launched more then once, both times, you failed to provide it.  "the MSI-based installer for some other program will spontaneously start" does not tell us anything helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not meaning to be obtuse and I appreciate your input... I have added the information you asked, I hope that is useful.

Comment: If this is replicable, I would suggest a ProcMon capture to see what is happening just before the other MSI kicks off.